# How to center elements of a stack view in a scroll view vertically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview, snapkit

I have [this](https://gist.github.com/falnatsheh/4059cff797d18acc3fa89355e6a93d2c) code I found to put a stack view with many buttons inside of a scroll view.

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var stackView: UIStackView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        for _ in 1 ..< 100 {
            let vw = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
            vw.setTitle("Button", for: [])
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(vw)
        }
    }
}
```

However this creates buttons on the left.

[image]

I am not sure how to put them in the center of the screen since the stack view just surrounds the existing views. Do I put layout constraints on the buttons themselves? Or is there an attribute of the stack view like alignment or distribution that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `UIStackView` to fill `UIScrollView` width:

```
stackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
     make.edges.equalToSuperview()
     make.width.equalToSuperview()
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try give width constraint to the buttons:

```
for _ in 1 ..< 100 {
        let vw = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
        vw.setTitle("Button", for: [])
        vw.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(view.frame.width)
        }
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vw)
    }
```

Output:

[image]